# java.exe still running in processes after running a batch job from .BAT file started with Pycron

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, tomcat, cmd

I have Windows 2003 server that has Pycron Scheduler starting some java batch jobs at certain times.  The problem is after a while, I have a bunch of java.exe and cmd.exe processes running after a couple of days if the server is not restarted.  For example here is the text from one of the .BAT files:

```
cd "C:\tomcat\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes"
java -classpath "C:\tomcat\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\lib\*";. com/mainapp/batchbjobs/job1
```

Is there something that I can add in addition to the 2 above lines in the batch file that will ensure java.exe and cmd.exe processes are closed after the jobs complete?  Additional information, some jobs take up to 30 minutes, and there are no command windows actually open when I log into the server.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: How does the main method of job1 looks like? In general, java process continues to run until the main method of the class specified in the Java command returns.

Comment: It returns void --- Main starts, creates an object for Job1, then that object calls a 'dojob' method that does the work.  This is surrounded by a try, catch, finally

Comment: So main doesn't return until dojob returns or throws an exception. When does dojob return? Can you attach the code?

Comment: doJob is void as well so it doesn't return anything, and of course doJob has a try catch finally within it as well.  The 40 or so jobs follow this format.  The catch throws exceptions and the finally does any housecleaning like closing database connections and such.

Comment: in pycron the jobs are started like: 01 0 * * * "c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" /k "C:\batfiles\doJob1.bat"

Comment: If a method is void, it still can return, meaning exit from the method. Method exits (returns) when it reaches the last closing bracket or return operator or throws an exception. Java machine continues to run until the main method exits (returns). My question was: Does your main method ever exits?